# cx_Oracle connection - "UTF-8" vs "utf8" encoding difference?

Tags: python, oracle, encoding, utf-8, cx-oracle

I have a app that loads some data from Oracle DB. It can contains Czech characters. When I create connection like that:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(job_conn_string, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

or

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(job_conn_string, encoding="utf-8", nencoding="utf-8")
```

then I got error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 87: invalid start
> byte

But when I create connection like that:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(job_conn_string, encoding="utf8", nencoding="utf8")
```

or

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(job_conn_string, encoding="UTF8", nencoding="UTF8")
```

everything works fine.

How is that possible? Is this usual thing that *UTF-8*/*utf-8* and *UTF8*/*utf8* are not interchangeable? The difference is in the dash?

EDIT:

The error occurs when I go through loop in cursor. When the row with czech character appears, it raises exception. The full error is:

> UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8',
> b'"ORA-29902: an error occurred while executing routine ODCIIndexStart()
> ORA-20004:84
> ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 12
> ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY", line 55
> ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA:TABLE", line 9
> ORA-06512: on line 2
> "", line 9\nORA-06512: na line 2\n',
> 87,
> 88,
> 'invalid start byte')

Comment: For Python, both are equivalent. But maybe the module for oracle do not use standard python convention.

Comment: As you can derive from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout , 0xfd is not a valid UTF-8 byte

Comment: Oracle has some quirks around codepages and this one is actually documented in [Setting the Client Character set](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html#setting-the-client-character-set) `Do not accidentally use UTF8, which Oracle uses to specify the older Unicode 3.0 Universal character set, CESU-8`. What's the character set of the database columns? What does that field contain?

Comment: `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY` spatial data are binary, not text. `The error occurs when I go through loop in cursor.` post the actual code.

Comment: Charset is AL32UTF8. This text 

"ORA-29902: an error occurred while executing routine ODCIIndexStart() ORA-20004:84 ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 12 ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY", line 55 ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA:TABLE"

is loged error after procedure fails. This is what I want to load and report - purpous of my app.

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to post more.  ArcSDE is an ESRI product, also used by ArcGIS and if you search for `ODCIIndexStart() ESRI` you'll find similar SO questions, ESRI bug reports and fixes. These are version-specific, you'll have to post the Oracle and SDE versions

Comment: How was the data written to the database? What does that field contain? If `utf8` was used, then the text may be in [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). `ODCIIndexStart` itself is used by Oracle Text and the fact that SDE is involved is weird. Is Oracle Text trying to access a spatial field?

Comment: Read the doc about using encoding & nencoding.  Bottom line is that these parameters are obsolete in the latest version of the driver: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/deprecations.html#deprecations

Answer (score 0):

Check valid character set names with this query:

```
select * 
from V$NLS_VALID_VALUES
where parameter = 'CHARACTERSET';
```

Be aware, Oracle character set `UTF8` is not the Unicode character set [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

`UTF8` in Oracle means [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). As long as you use the Basic Multilingual Plane, i.e. characters below U+FFFF it is identical to UTF-8

Oracle character set for UTF-8 is `AL32UTF8`